# Modify content of .sppkg file before uploading to SPO app catalog using DevOps pipelines

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to run a SPFx web part through DevOps build pipeline once, and have the same artifacts be deployable to any environment.

Currently I have a setup where there are **#{PlaceHolders}#** in the code which are to be replaced by the Replace Tokens task in a DevOps release pipeline. To do this I have added an Extract activity to unzip the .sppkg package, after which I replace the tokens in the generated .zip file, and then I archive the files back into a .sppkg package.

The issue I run into is that seemingly, SharePoint doesn't like me tampering with it's .sppkg files. In the app catalog, I get this in the column App Package Error Message whenever I have replaced the tokens:

The package contains the wrong number of relationships for relationship type `'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/relationships/package-manifest'. Expected: '1'. Actual: '0'.`

Any clue on how I can safely modify the .sppkg package is appreciated, or how I otherwise can implement environment variables into my SFPx web parts after the solution is packaged.

The goal is to being able to promote one and the same build to subsequent environments in Azure DevOps.

[image: Build promotion]

**Edit providing release pipeline details**

Using the standard Extract files and Archive files tasks, these are the settings used:

Archive patterns:
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyProjectFolder/drop/SharePoint/solution/my-package.sppkg

Destination folder:
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyProjectFolder/drop/SharePoint/solution/extracts

Root folder or file to archive:
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyProjectFolder/drop/sharepoint/solution/extracts

Archive file to create:
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyProjectFolder/drop/sharepoint/solution/my-package.sppkg

Also I tried modifying the .sppkg package locally after also building locally but to the same result. So I'm thinking there might be a signature that gets added to .sppkg packages that's looking for length, and if changed, it might get denied?

Comment: What tasks/steps do you use to do the `Extract activity to unzip the .sppkg package, after which I replace the tokens in the generated .zip file, and then I archive the files back into a .sppkg package`, can you share some details about your build definitions?

Comment: Have you tried to unzip the .sppkg package locally and modify something in it, then archive it again. What's the result if you deploy it to App Package?

Comment: Sure, more details provided in the post!

Comment: It looks like that is not supported even locally. I think you need to use `gulp ...` command to generate the sppkg package after modifying the content within it.

Comment: Yep, same conclusion here. I'll need to move packaging the .sppkg file to the release pipeline when I get the chance to revisit this. I'll update here if/when I do (classic thing to write then never do just that, but I'll try :) )

Comment: I was running into the same issue using PowerShell "Compress-Archive", but when I switched to 7zip I was able to extract the sppkg, replace placeholders, re-zip and the app catalog accepted the new sppkg

Comment: The "Compress-Archive" issue for me was also fixed by updating Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive to > 1.2.3.0 see: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1382839/zip-files-expand-with-backslashes-on-linux-no-subdirectories) but not sure if that's the same issue with DevOps (it was the same error message)

Comment: After all this time my project had reason to revisit this issue, and could confirm that the compress-archive activity was indeed the culprit. Thank you @JBart! If you write an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into the same issue using PowerShell "Compress-Archive", but when I switched to 7zip I was able to extract the sppkg, replace placeholders, re-zip and the app catalog accepted the new sppkg.

The "Compress-Archive" issue for me was also fixed by updating Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive to > 1.2.3.0,  see: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1382839/zip-files-expand-with-backslashes-on-linux-no-subdirectories)